# How to append tar without full path

Tags: tar

Is there a way to append a file into a specific dir inside a tar file?

I have dir1/TarFile.tar. Inside the TarFile.tar there is dir2.

I want to append file.txt (in dir 1) to TarFile.tar under dir2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't do this on the fly. You can create directory `dir2`, move there the file `file.txt` and update the archive:

```
cd dir1
mkdir -p dir2
mv file.txt dir2/
tar uvf TarFile.tar dir2/file.txt
```